# How to concatenate two row values

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am using the below query where I am concatenating four values and it is working for me, but now for one of the column (ADDRESS_LINE), I have two values and I want to concatenate with all.

```
    (SELECT LDR.ADDRESS_LINE
  || ' , '
  || LOC.CITY
  ||' , '
  || LOC.postal_code
  ||' , '
  || LOC.country_code3_gid
FROM LOCATION LOC,
  LOCATION_ADDRESS LDR,
  SHIPMENT SH
WHERE SH.SOURCE_LOCATION_GID = LOC.LOCATION_GID
AND LOC.LOCATION_GID         = LDR.LOCATION_GID
AND SH.SHIPMENT_GID          = :P_SHIPMENT_ID
)
```

But now for ADDRESS_LINE I have three values coming which I want to include in the same query.

I know we can achieve this with LISTAGG but somehow i am not getting the proper result

Comment: for LISTAGG to work, you need a group by clause

Comment: Show how you have implemented `LISTAGG` in your query. Show the result you got and the result you expected.

Comment: BTW: You should not use this out-dated join syntax of the 1980s. Use explicit joins instead (`from ... inner join ... on ...`). And I would not join the shipment table anyway, as you don't select any data from it and it's not needed to join the other two tables. Use `where loc.location_gid = (select source_location_gid from shipment where shipment_gid = :p_shipment_id)` instead for readability.

Comment: One location can have several addresses? What then is the content of its address_line? Please show table data plus desired result.

Comment: You should provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: ?? do you mean you have two or three rows in your table, each containing a different "line" from `address_line`? You should raise serious questions about this data model, who came up with it? One single text value, in a single row in a table in the database, may have embedded newline characters; splitting a multi-line address over multiple rows in a table is crazy!

Answer (score 0):

This is your query, cleaned up a bit:

```
SELECT (LDR.ADDRESS_LINE || ' , ' || LOC.CITY ||' , ' ||
        LOC.postal_code ||' , ' || LOC.country_code3_gid
       )
FROM LOCATION LOC JOIN
     LOCATION_ADDRESS LDR
     ON LOC.LOCATION_GID = LDR.LOCATION_GID JOIN
     SHIPMENT SH
     ON SH.SOURCE_LOCATION_GID = LOC.LOCATION_GID
WHERE SH.SHIPMENT_GID = :P_SHIPMENT_ID;
```

Sample data and desired results would clarify what you really want.  What follows are some ideas on reasonable speculation.

You can combine these into a single line by using `listagg()`:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(LDR.ADDRESS_LINE || ' , ' || LOC.CITY ||' , ' ||
               LOC.postal_code ||' , ' || LOC.country_code3_gid,
               ';'
              ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ?)
FROM LOCATION LOC JOIN
     LOCATION_ADDRESS LDR
     ON LOC.LOCATION_GID = LDR.LOCATION_GID JOIN
     SHIPMENT SH
     ON SH.SOURCE_LOCATION_GID = LOC.LOCATION_GID
WHERE SH.SHIPMENT_GID = :P_SHIPMENT_ID;
```

The `?` is for the column that specifies the address line ordering.

Note that this is susceptible to overflowing strings.  Also, you might want a `GROUP BY`.  If you wanted all address lines within the same city, then you can do:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(LDR.ADDRESS_LINE || ' , ' || LOC.CITY ||' , ' ||
               LOC.postal_code ||' , ' || LOC.country_code3_gid,
               ';'
              ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ?)
FROM LOCATION LOC JOIN
     LOCATION_ADDRESS LDR
     ON LOC.LOCATION_GID = LDR.LOCATION_GID JOIN
     SHIPMENT SH
     ON SH.SOURCE_LOCATION_GID = LOC.LOCATION_GID
WHERE SH.SHIPMENT_GID = :P_SHIPMENT_ID
GROUP BY LOC.CITY, LOC.postal_code, LOC.country_code3_gid;
```